# flotchart.org: how to draw scatterplots with full circle as symbol?

Tags: javascript, html, graphics, flot

using flotchart.org , I would like to substitute the default 'circle' shape to represent a point, with just a similar circle, but filled with the color of the series; by example, with color "red" associated to a certain series: 
the symbol I would like to represent is, using HTML5 canvas API:

```
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");ctx.beginPath(); ctx.arc(100,75,3,0,2*Math.PI); ctx.fillStyle="red"; ctx.fill();
```

But I can't obtain the result, coding what suggested by [flotchart documentation](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-data-series).

As suggested in above doc, in options I wrote the custom function:

```
          points: {
            show: true,
            radius: 2,
            symbol: 
                function fullCircle(ctx, x, y, radius, shadow) {        
                    ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, shadow ? Math.PI : Math.PI * 2, false);
                    ctx.fill();
                },
```

The ctx.fill do not work as desired: the circle is filled with BLACK color and just after pointing, instead I would like to fill the circle with the color associated with the corresponding series, before focusing the point...

sorry for my ignorance about canvas ctx...

Answer (score 1):

there is a combination of flot settings to draw filled circles (discs) to represent series points
quoted from the documentation https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md

> "fill" is whether the shape should be filled. For lines, this produces
> area graphs. You can use "fillColor" to specify the color of the fill.
> **If "fillColor" evaluates to false** (default for everything except
> points which are filled with white), **the fill color is auto-set to the
> color of the data series**. You can **adjust the opacity** of the fill by
> setting **"fill" to a number between 0 (fully transparent) and 1 (fully
> opaque)**.

so you simply set `series.points.fillColor` option to `false` (to use series color, or to whatever color you like).
and `series.points.fill` to `1` for full opacity. Just play around with the fiddle.

Here is the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m0ts8cnd/6/).